# How do you extract the URL from a page after redirecting it using ui4j?

Tags: html, web-scraping, ui4j

I have written some code using ui4j, and it has redirected to another page. I need to extract the URL from the current page.

```
BrowserEngine browser = BrowserFactory.getWebKit();
Page page = browser.navigate("somewebsite");
//some oprations have been perfomed
//need to extract the URL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the JavaScript capabilities of ui4j:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
  try (final Page page = getWebKit().navigate("http://www.xing.de")) {
    System.out.println("Example: " + page.executeScript("window.location.href"));
  }
}
```

The output for this particular example would be:

```
Example: https://www.xing.com/de
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  You have no idea how much you've helped me out here.